# A* Pathfinding - Waiting Behaviour

Tags: python, simulation, shortest-path, path-finding, a-star

I am implementing an A* pathfinding algorithm in a simulation model. The costs in the map that agents navigate over changes over time. In other words, there is a different 2D grid at each time step. In addition, I need agents to be able to decide to "wait" at a given location on the grid, if waiting allows them to take an overall lower cost path.

My code seems to do this, but it is very slow, and seems to become substantially slower with longer paths and larger maps. I would eventually like to have agents navigate anywhere (including diagonally) on a 50x50 grid, so I need a way to speed it up.

Any suggestions on how to speed up the search?

For reference, here is my current code, with this map and start end, I would expect the following path to be returned:

[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 6)]

```
# %%
import heapq

class Node:
    def __init__(self, x, y, cost, parent=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.cost = cost
        self.parent = parent

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cost < other.cost

def heuristic(node, goal):
    # Calculate the Manhattan distance as the heuristic
    return abs(node.x - goal.x) + abs(node.y - goal.y)

def astar_with_variable_costs(fullgrid, start, goal):
    open_set = []
    closed_set = set()

    start_node = Node(start[0], start[1], 0)
    goal_node = Node(goal[0], goal[1], 0)

    heapq.heappush(open_set, start_node)

    while open_set:
        
        current = heapq.heappop(open_set)

        if current.x == goal_node.x and current.y == goal_node.y:
            path = []
            while current:
                
                path.append((current.x, current.y))
                current = current.parent
            path.reverse()
            return path
        
        # Construct the path from the goal node to the start node
        path = []
        current2 = current
        while current2:
            path.append((current2.x, current2.y))
            current2 = current2.parent
        path.reverse()

        grid = fullgrid[min(len(path), len(fullgrid)-1)]

        closed_set.add((current.x, current.y))

        for dx, dy in [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (0, 0)]:
            x, y = current.x + dx, current.y + dy
            if 0 <= x < len(grid) and 0 <= y < len(grid[0]) and grid[x][y] != 0 and ((x, y) not in closed_set or (x,y)==(current.x,current.y)):
                new_cost = current.cost + grid[x][y]

                new_node = Node(x, y, new_cost, current)

                if new_node not in open_set:
                    heapq.heappush(open_set, new_node)

    return None

# Example usage:
matrix_3d = [
        [
        # Another 10x10 matrix with different values
        [101, 1102, 1013, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110],
        [100, 1000, 1113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120],
        [1, 1212, 1123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130],
        [131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140],
        [141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150],
        [151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160],
        [161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170],
        [171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180],
        [181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190],
        [191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200]
    ],

    [
        [101, 1000, 1013, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110],
        [100, 1000, 1113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120],
        [1, 1122, 1123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130],
        [131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140],
        [141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150],
        [151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160],
        [161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170],
        [171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180],
        [181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190],
        [191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200]
    ],

    [
        [101, 102, 1103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110],
        [100, 1000, 1000, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120],
        [1, 1212, 1000, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130],
        [131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140],
        [141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150],
        [151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160],
        [161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170],
        [171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180],
        [181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190],
        [191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200]
    ],
    [
        [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110],
        [100, 1000, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120],
        [1, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130],
        [131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140],
        [141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150],
        [151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160],
        [161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170],
        [171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180],
        [181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190],
        [191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200]
    ],


    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
        [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
        [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
        [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
        [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
        [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
        [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
        [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
    ],

    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
        [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
        [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
        [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
        [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
        [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
        [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
        [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
    ]
]

start = (0, 0)
goal = (6, 6)

path = astar_with_variable_costs(matrix_3d, start, goal)
print(path)
```

Comment: I don’t know how the speed compares to what you did, but you can get an *optimal* solution by doing A* on three dimensions, and that’s the first approach I would try since it’s very plain.

Comment: Thanks I did try that earlier but I ran into a couple issues with that approach. One was still speed. Another was that without restricting the neighbours, agents moved backward in time. The most important was that I had to define a point in time I wanted them to arrive at, which is not something I want to have to specify in my model.

Comment: It sounds like when you treated time as a third dimension you didn't implement the generate the successor nodes properly. Your agents can't go backwards in time unless you give them permission to. It also sounds like you're thinking in terms of a "goal node" rather than in terms of a "goal function".